# List the class names of all the child elements (Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am having the following structure:

```
<div class="outter">
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">3</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and trying to get inside the parent div and output a `console.log("Elements exist")` if div with classname `"child"` contains `is-visible`.

I have managed to get inside the `.parent div` but not sure how to get inside the child elements.

The JS code I have used is:

```
var n = document.getelementById("outter");

if(n.classList.contains("parent")){
   var m = n.getAttribute("class");
   console.log(m);
}
```

I know there are quite a lot of conversations and tutorials but it seems that I can't find one that resolves my problem. Can you please help?

Comment: You should look into how to use the debugger in your favorite browser. For instance, in this case, you'd get an error because the name of the function is `getElementById`. After fixing that, you'd notice that it was returning `null` because your `div` has a `class` of "outter", not an `id` of "outter". Finally, look into the function [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or the more modern [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 1):

`n` refers to the `outter` DIV (except you should be looking it up by class, not ID). The class names you're looking for are on elements inside it, so accessing `n`'s class list won't work for this.

You can use a selector:

```
n = document.querySelector("#outter");
if (n.querySelector(".parent .child.is-visible")) {
    console.log("Elements exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.childNodes` to get all of an element's children.

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">3</div>
     <div class="child is-visible">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];
var children = parent.childNodes;
for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
  var classname = children[i].className;
  if(classname&&classname.includes("child is-visible")){
    console.log("Class name contains child and is-visible");
  }
  children[i].innerHTML += " <b>Child</b>";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** with this selector `div.outter div.parent .child.is-visible`, this way you're selecting only those children within `div .parent` which is within of `div.outter`

> ### [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
>
> The Element method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Look at this code snippet with DIVs `.is-visible` grouped by different DIVs, this is to show how it works the selector `div.outter div.parent .child.is-visible`

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll("div.outter div.parent .child.is-visible");

console.log(children.length) // prints 4 and not 8 which is OK.
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">3</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myanother-outter">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">3</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to check the first div with class `.outter` then use the function **[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**, this function will return the first div regardless of the amount of div with class `.outter`.

This approach checks for the result of `querySelector` because if the DOM doesn't have any DIV element with class `.outter` the result will be null.

> ### [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
>
> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```
var children = firstOutter ? firstOutter.querySelectorAll("div.parent .child.is-visible") : []
```

```js
var firstOutter = document.querySelector('div.outter:nth-child(1)');    
var children = firstOutter ? firstOutter.querySelectorAll("div.parent .child.is-visible") : [];

console.log(children.length) // prints 2 and not 6 which is OK.
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outter">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child is-visible">1</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">2</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">3</div>
    <div class="child is-visible">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I limit that to run only within the first outter div if they have the same class names?

Comment: this is pre-defining the first one. What if it needs to be the second one. Because I have a click event attached I will need it to be the current. Can I use something similar to "this" (from jQuery) for current outter?

Comment: @John you can use this selector `div.outter:nth-child(xyz)` where `xyz` is the index of the elements, in this case I'm using the index `1`.